# Is there a way to get the diazo abslolute prefix in an xsl section in a diazo rules.xml file?

Tags: xslt, themes, plone, diazo

looking for something like:

```
<replace css:content="#portal-logo img">
   <img src="{$absolute_prefix}/images/logo.png" />
</replace>
```

Currently gets this error:

```
runtime error, element 'img' [318:0]
Variable 'absolute_prefix' has not been declared. [0:0]
```

Comment: In this page there is one example, at the end (Compiling the theme in Python code): http://docs.diazo.org/en/latest/compiler.html

Comment: thanks Fernando. I think that that example seems to be about passing in the absolute_prefix, but I actually want to use it in my rules file.

Comment: Sorry arterrey, I thought the problem was you was not passing it. Did you add the param? `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"><xsl:param name="absolute_prefix" />` I don't know with Diazo, but with others technologies you must add it in order to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you'll probably want to use the `base` variable, provided you're using Diazo via `plone.app.theming`, which provides the Zope `BASE1` variable as an XSLT parameter:

```
<replace css:content="#portal-logo img">
   <img src="{$base}/images/logo.png" />
</replace>
```

Details of the theme parameters available by default are found at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.theming#theme-parameters.

If you're using straight Diazo, then you'll need to pass such a parameter in from your environment.